# Prepare table column using PHP array

Tags: php

I have this PHP array ($widgets):

```
Array
(
    [company_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => advance google map
            [1] => Advanced Accordion
        )

    [company_2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  premium tabs
            [1] => premium alert box
            [2] => premium animated gradient
        )

    [company_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => accordion
            [1] => advance tab
            [2] => advanced accordion
            [3] => advanced toggle
            [4] => behance feed
        )

    [company_4] => Array
        (
            [0] => audio player
            [1] => audio playlist
        )

    [company_5] => Array
        (
            [0] => advance accordion
            [1] => advance flip box
            [2] => advanced heading
        )

)
```

I want to show each company to separate column and under each column, there should be a corresponding option (each columns array elements):

**Something like that I want:**

```
<tr>
    <td>Company_1</td>
    <td>Company_2</td>
    <td>Company_3</td>
    <td>Company_4</td>
    <td>Company_5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>advance google map</td>
    <td>premium tabs</td>
    <td>accordion</td>
    <td>audio player</td>
    <td>advance accordion</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Advanced Accordion</td>
    <td>premium alert box</td>
    <td>advance tab</td>
    <td>audio playlist</td>
    <td>advance flip box</td>
</tr>

and so on... like that
```

I am getting tried with this below code:

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    // echo "<tr>";
    //     echo "<td></td>";
    //     echo "<td></td>";
    //     echo "<td></td>";
    //     echo "<td></td>";
    //     echo "<td></td>";
    // echo "</tr>";
    
    echo $count = count($widgets);
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){    
       
        echo "<td>";
        foreach($widgets['company_'.$i] as $key => $value){
            echo $widgets['company_'.$i][$key];
            echo '<hr/>';
        }
        echo "</td>";
    
        // foreach($widgets['company_'.$i] as $wid){
        //      echo "<tr>";
        //      echo "<td>$wid</td>";
        //      echo "</tr>";
        // }
        
       
        
    }
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: And what if there are 100 compaies in the array?

Comment: I have fixed 5 companies and each company has different values

Comment: To clarify, what are you expecting in place of `<td> ---- </td>`? For example, for the first column are you expecting `advance google map, Advanced Accordion` in that single cell? Or are you only expecting `advance google map` and then `Advanced Accordion` would be in the next row down in the same column?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I am updating my question a bit more...

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you want

```
$widgets = [
    'company_1' => ['advance google map', 'Advanced Accordion'],
    'company_2' => ['premium tabs', 'premium alert box', 'premium animated gradient'],
    'company_3' => ['accordion', 'advance tab', 'advanced accordion', 'advanced toggle', 'behance feed'],
    'company_4' => ['audio player', 'audio playlist'],
    'company_5' => ['advance accordion','advance flip box', 'advanced heading']
    ];

$max = 0;

$titles = array_keys($widgets);
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($titles as $title){
    echo "<td>$title</td>";
    // get largest company array as we pass through thsi array
    $max = $max < count($widgets[$title]) ? count($widgets[$title]) : $max;
}
echo "</tr>";
#echo PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($widgets as $company){
        if ( isset($company[$i]) ){
            echo "<td>$company[$i]</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    #echo PHP_EOL;
}
echo "</table>";
```

RESULT

```
<table class='table table-bordered'><tr><td>company_1</td><td>company_2</td><td>company_3</td><td>company_4</td><td>company_5</td></tr>
<tr><td>advance google map</td><td>premium tabs</td><td>accordion</td><td>audio player</td><td>advance accordion</td></tr>
<tr><td>Advanced Accordion</td><td>premium alert box</td><td>advance tab</td><td>audio playlist</td><td>advance flip box</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>premium animated gradient</td><td>advanced accordion</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>advanced heading</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>advanced toggle</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>behance feed</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working as expected. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Yes, Now, I can see what I am looking for :)

Comment: Missed some Table row statements, now added

Comment: You are awesome : )